# Select column under specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

for example I have the following table:

```
id_1 | id_2 | id_3 | name
1    |      |      | smith
B    |AF    |2     | waterman
C    |3     |      | goldman
```

I want the name of the following ids ('1', 'AF', 'C'). The output should look like this

```
id | name
1  | smith
AF | waterman
C  | goldman
```

With the following code I am able to select the name but I dont know how I can select the right id field

```
SELECT name 
FROM table 
WHERE (id_1 IN ('1', 'AF', 'C')) OR
(id_2 IN ('1', 'AF', 'C')) OR
(id_3 IN ('1', 'AF', 'C'));
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is your wished result ?

Comment: @echo_Me it says so right there: `The output should look like this`

Comment: This *looks* like poor design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CASE`

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN id_1 IN ('1', 'AF', 'C') THEN id_1 
WHEN id_2 IN ('1', 'AF', 'C') THEN id_2 
WHEN id_3 IN ('1', 'AF', 'C') THEN id_3 
ELSE 0 END ) id
,name 
FROM table 
WHERE (id_1 IN ('1', 'AF', 'C')) OR
(id_2 IN ('1', 'AF', 'C')) OR
(id_3 IN ('1', 'AF', 'C'));
```